# Doesn't work on DotCloud

Tags: production, dotcloud, strongloop

I trying to launch app with StrongOps on DotCloud, but information about process/app does not appear in dashboard.Locally it works fine. 
API-key and APP-name passed directly in the code. Also, i try to set ENV vars (SL_APP_NAME and SL_KEY), but no result.

App name - is random string and shoudn't represent any real variable, right?

Logs. Only this

```
    strong-agent profiling
    Cluster controls unavailable.
```

My code

```
    require('strong-agent').profile(KEY,APP_NAME);
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "slovohvat",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "strongAgentKey": "607dbd9b5cd4c6dd20ae05d128b63652",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
  "dependencies": {
  "express": "3.4.0",
  "nunjucks": "0.1.9",
  "socket.io": "0.9.16",
  "bigint-node": "1.0.1",
  "connect": "2.9.0",
  "request":"2.27.0",
  "node-logentries": "0.0.2",
  "redis": "0.8.6",
  "socket.io-clusterhub": "0.2.0",
  "connect-redis": "1.4.x",
  "async": "0.2.9",
  "nodetime": ">=0.8.0",
  "emailjs ":"0.3.6",
  "strong-agent":"0.2.18",
  "raygun": "~0.3.0"
},
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD"
}
```

And my dotcloud.yaml

```
www:
  type: nodejs
  approot: app
  process: node app.js 0
  config:
    node_version: v0.8.x
    smtp_server: smtp.XXX.org
    smtp_port: 587
    smtp_username: XX@XX.XX
    smtp_password: XXX
data:
  type: redis
```

strongloop.json exists at same dir as dotcloud.yaml and looks correct.

Please, give me any advice i should to try.
Thank you. And sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 3):

You should create a strongloop.json by using the `slc strongops` command, it will write the config file after you login. It sounds like you might already have done that.

Note that if you have a stongloop.json, you should NOT provide any args to .profile(). The API arguments are a mechanism for fine-grained control, and for environments when you cannot deploy a config file.

Also, you should remove strongAgentKey from your package.json (it lets anyone on stackoverflow publish data to your account), and the env variables. It sounds like you are configuring strong-agent using all 4 mechanisms at the same time! Sorry about the confusion.

After clearing the redundant config, you should be able to run your app (`node .`). Login to your strongops console, and see the app after a few minutes as data starts coming in.

If that doesn't work, we will need more details. It might be easier to work through this over irc or email, check out our support page: http://strongloop.com/developers/forums/